# Agrupación de datos en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito mostrar mis datos agrupados por el campo máquina y otro campo llamado lado, este último es calculado como `i` o `d` dependiendo de una expresión:

```
SELECT  maquina
      , CASE   
            WHEN posicion <= 84 THEN 'i'   
            WHEN posicion > 84 THEN 'd'   
        END lado
      , COUNT(*) posiciones 
FROM   improductivas 
GROUP BY 1, 2 
ORDER BY 3
```

Al ejecutar la sentencia me marca el siguiente error:

> Mens. 164, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 7
>   Todas las expresiones GROUP BY deben contener al menos una columna que no sea una referencia exterior.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A menos que uses una función agregada para obtener el campo 'lado' la consulta debiera ser así:

```
SELECT  maquina, 
        CASE   
            WHEN posicion <= 84 THEN 'i'   
            WHEN posicion > 84 THEN 'd'   
        END lado
      , COUNT(*) posiciones 
FROM   improductivas 
GROUP BY maquina, 
        CASE   
            WHEN posicion <= 84 THEN 'i'   
            WHEN posicion > 84 THEN 'd'   
        END 
ORDER BY 3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona bien, pasa que ahora no comprendo por que se tiene que poner el case en el GROUP BY también, no se puede usar un alias?

Comment: Si es un incordio tener que repetir el código, pero entiendo que no es posible, los alias seguramente se resuelven al final de la consulta (por eso funcionan en un ORDER BY)